# Facebook Comment box customization

Tags: css, facebook, comments

Does someone know the proper CSS classes to use in order to customize the Facebook Commenting Box beyond the "light" or "dark" color schemes that Facebook provides?

I want the box to be designed more in line with the colors of my site.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

This is the commenting box I am referring to.

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to your query?